# Remove the part of string after the last occurrence in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a string that has the path of the file stored in it.

```
path = \home\linux\testfile\abc\work
```

now I want to write a function with which I can remove all the characters occurring after the **`last '\\'`**.
So,

```
new_path = \home\linux\testfile\abc
```

Is there a way I can do it?
Slicing doesn't help because the number of characters after the last '\' isn't fixed. I know i need to post an attempt but i don't even understand how do i start this.

Comment: please work with `os` import or related

Comment: Why does slicing not work? Slice it and get the last element by using sliced_path[-1] on the resulting list. Or use rsplit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `rsplit` to start from the right and only split one time.

```
>>> path = '\home\linux\testfile\abc\work'
>>> path.rsplit('\\', 1)
['\\home\\linux\\testfile\\abc', 'work']

>>> path.rsplit('\\', 1)[0]
'\\home\\linux\\testfile\\abc'
```

Comment: This works for me i used to think that split removes after the first occurrence.

Comment: @Pushpesh, welcome, `split` strat from `left` BUT `rsplit` start from `right` and you can also control how many split

Answer (score 2):

Why not simply use pathlib? Path objects never leave trailing path delimiters.

```py
from pathlib import Path

path = Path("\home\linux\testfile\abc\work") 
new_path = path.parent
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try with `os` library.

```
>>> import os
>>> data = os.path.split(r"\home\linux\testfile\abc\work")
>>> data[1]
'work'
>>> data[0]
'\\home\\linux\\testfile\\abc'
```

Answer (score 1):

Does it mean that I get the parent directory

```
>>> a="/home/pro"
>>> os.path.dirname(a)
'/home'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
path = "\\home\\linux\\testfile\\abc\\work"
pat = path.split("\\")

pat.pop()

path = "\\".join(pat)


print(path)
```

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/azjIS.png)

Comment: How is this a significant improvement over the accepted answer?

Answer (score -1):

You can use `head, tail = os.path.split(path)`

Check [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.split)

Comment: This only works if the last part of the directory is called "work"...

Comment: Yes, i know, i was giving an example, then a reference to what i used, and he can work with it. He can just os.path.split(path) then work with (head,tail) output.

Comment: Yes, but OP asked for a function that works generally, not an example...

Comment: This approach won't work for me because the last part isn't fixed.

Comment: I have edited my answer. you can just take any path into a variable and pass it to split()